# Find repeated numbers sequence (I Can't use regex)

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, matching

I need to create a function that returns true if I have an occurrence of 4 repeated numbers or more. I use the Oracle 9i version, for this reason I can not use the regex.
e.g.:

```
0000234567, 0111112345, 2333345678, 3333333333
```

Comment: why can't you use regex?

Comment: What to remove and from which column, any sample data ?

Comment: Can you be more precise? You want to remove 00000001 also? What about 9999919999? What is the rule?

Comment: And what do you mean by "remove" and "list"?  That is not part of SQL vocabulary.

Comment: the real difficulty here is to understand your question. you'd probably get help if you gave some examples of input and output (i.e. for this input this output is correct)

Comment: I can not use regex because of the oracle version I use. The version I use is 9i.

In fact, I'd like to create a function that returns true if I have an occurrence of 4 repeated numbers or more(inside a number).
E.g.:
1234444567 or 1111234567

Comment: @tonypdmtr, thanks for the note. In fact, this is a request I received from a client. Also, in my region these numbers are considered invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check a string for 4 consecutive repeating characters:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f46bc9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '0000234567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0111112345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2333456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0123456666' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0123456789' FROM DUAL
/

CREATE FUNCTION check_For_Repeats(
  i_value   VARCHAR2,
  i_repeats INTEGER DEFAULT 4
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  p PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  c CHAR(1)     := SUBSTR( i_value, p, 1 );
BEGIN
  IF i_repeats < 2 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  FOR i IN 2 .. LENGTH( i_value ) LOOP
    IF SUBSTR( i_value, i, 1 ) = c THEN
      IF i >= p + i_repeats - 1 THEN
        RETURN 0;
      END IF;
    ELSE
      p := i;
      c := SUBSTR( i_value, p, 1 );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 1;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value, check_For_Repeats( value ) FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f46bc9/1/0)**:

```
|      VALUE | CHECK_FOR_REPEATS(VALUE) |
|------------|--------------------------|
| 0000234567 |                        0 |
| 0111112345 |                        0 |
| 2333456789 |                        1 |
| 0123456666 |                        0 |
| 0123456789 |                        1 |
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there are only 10 possible digits, removing phone numbers with sequences of 4 equal digits or more (according to your comment) is as simple as:

```
DELETE
FROM MyTable
WHERE
    phonenumber LIKE '%0000%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%1111%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%2222%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%3333%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%4444%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%5555%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%6666%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%7777%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%8888%' OR
    phonenumber LIKE '%9999%'
```

---

The test as a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IsRepeatingDigit(s varchar2)
  RETURN number IS
BEGIN
  IF s LIKE '%0000%' OR
     s LIKE '%1111%' OR
     s LIKE '%2222%' OR
     s LIKE '%3333%' OR
     s LIKE '%4444%' OR
     s LIKE '%5555%' OR
     s LIKE '%6666%' OR
     s LIKE '%7777%' OR
     s LIKE '%8888%' OR
     s LIKE '%9999%'
  THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
```

I would not return a boolean, as the boolean type is somewhat restricted in Oracle. You can use it in PL/SQL but not in plain SQL.